# Dual stack Ipv6 and ipv4 together causing failures

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4

I have a new-ish Windows 10 Creator's Updated laptop which is getting "Connection Reset" errors on some websites, such as https://xkcd.com. The connection reset errors are intermittent and not present on every website.

If I disable *either* the ipv4 *or* the ipv6 stack (doesn't matter which) the problem vanishes, and it appears to be inflicting only this computer.

What should I be looking at to troubleshoot this problem>

Some details:

- The connection is an Xfinity/Comcast cable service connection, at 200
  Mbits down/12 Mbits up.
- It occurs when connected directly to the cable modem; I have ruled out other networking hardware.
- Among the
  devices I have to test with, only this computer (Win10 Creator's
  Update) is having the problem. An android smartphone and another
  Win10 machine running the Anniversary Update do not have this
  problem. Could it be a bug in the latest Win10?

---

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ALIEN24
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 9E-B6-D0-D9-E1-DF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : **************
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ********:e61a:9a6b(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : ********:935b:9938(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f970:d33d:e61a:9a6b%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.112(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, May 31, 2017 2:11:54 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, May 31, 2017 5:11:54 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1aa6:f7ff:fe78:e0f0%13
                                       192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 144488144
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-49-14-BC-D4-81-D7-88-7D-C3
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:558:feed::1
                                       2001:558:feed::2
                                       192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:953c:20c7:3978:cd76:42d9(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::20c7:3978:cd76:42d9%19(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 469762048
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-49-14-BC-D4-81-D7-88-7D-C3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: I've tested this against a second Win10 Creator's machine in my house, where this is not a problem. So, It is not a problem with Win10 Creator's update.

Comment: You have a Killer network adapter. I’ve seen their drivers causing issues a lot. Try updating the driver. If you can, try a different adapter.

Comment: what do you know. It looks like it might have been the "Advanced Stream Detect" setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition cleared up immediately after I deactivated the "Advanced Stream Detect" feature of the "Killer Control Center", which shipped with the computer.

Comment: Just discovered this myself. Bizarre.

Comment: No kidding. Chores like this keep me from doing "real work".